# If $A\thicksim B$ and $C\thicksim D$, then $^{A}C\thicksim$ $^{B}D$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is the following proof Correct?

**SOME PRELIMARY NOTATION**

- $A\thicksim B\Leftrightarrow$ There is a bijection from A to B
- **$5.3.2$** - if $f:A\to B$ and $f^{-1}:B\to A$ then $f\circ f^{-1} = i_B = \{(x,x)| x\in B\}$ and $f\circ f^{-1} =i_A=\{(y,y)|y\in A\}$

**Theorem.** For any sets $A$ and $B$ let $^{A}B$ denote the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$. If $A\thicksim B$ and $C\thicksim D$, then $^{A}C\thicksim$ $^{B}D$.

**Proof.** Assume that $A\thicksim B$ and $C\thicksim D$ consequently we invoke the existence $h_1:A\to B$ and $h_2:C\to D$ such that $h_1$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$ and $h_2$ is a bijection from $C$ to $D$.

We know define the the function $\mathcal{Z}:^{A}C\to$ $^{B}D$ and show that is a bijection from $^{A}C$ to $^{B}D$.
$$\mathcal{Z}(f) = h_2\circ f\circ h_1^{-1}$$

Now let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be arbitrary functions in $^{A}C$ and assume that $\mathcal{Z}(f_1) = \mathcal{Z}(f_2)$ consequently $h_2\circ f_1\circ h_1^{-1} = h_2\circ f_2\circ h_1^{-1}$, making use of theorem $\textbf{5.3.2}$ we have  the following equivalences.
$$\Leftrightarrow h_2\circ f_1\circ h_1^{-1} = h_2\circ f_2\circ h_1^{-1}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow h_2\circ f_1\circ (h_1^{-1}\circ h_1) = h_2\circ f_2\circ (h_1^{-1}\circ h_1)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow h_2\circ f_1\circ i_A = h_2\circ f_2\circ i_A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow h_2\circ f_1= h_2\circ f_2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (h_2^{-1}\circ h_2)\circ f_1= (h_2^{-1}\circ h_2)\circ f_2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow i_C\circ f_1 = i_C\circ f_2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow f_1 = f_2$$
Since our choice of $f_1$ and $f_2$ was arbitrary it follows that $\mathcal{Z}(f)$ is *one-to-one*.

Now let $g$ be an arbitrary function in $^B{D}$ and consider the function $f = h_2^{-1}\circ g\circ h_1$ consequently we see that $\mathcal{Z}(f) = h_2\circ(h_2^{-1}\circ g\circ h_1)\circ h_1^{-1}$
using associativity of function composition in conjunction with theorem $\textbf{5.3.2}$ we have the following equivalences.
$$\Leftrightarrow (h_2\circ h_2^{-1})\circ g\circ (h_1 \circ h_1^{-1})$$
$$\Leftrightarrow i_D \circ g\circ i_B$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (i_D \circ g)\circ i_B$$
$$\Leftrightarrow g\circ i_B$$
$$\Leftrightarrow g$$
Thus $\mathcal{Z}(f) = g$, since our choice of $g$ was arbitrary it follows that $\mathcal{Z}$ is *onto*.

With this we have established that $\mathcal{Z}$ is a bijection from $^{A}C$ to $^{B}D$ consequently $^{A}C\thicksim$ $^{B}D$.

Comment: Please avoid all $\rm\LaTeX$ titles.

Comment: I edited my answer as I spotted a tiny issue with notation in the "onto" part... The idea is correct, it is just how you've written it.

Comment: @user8734617 Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all correct and very good.

I would just avoid writing equivalences ($ \Leftrightarrow$) where implications ($\Rightarrow$) suffice... In essence you are claiming more in each row, and there is more to check, so it is more work both for you and for whoever needs to verify your proof.

A tiny additional niggle... In the proof of "onto", I presume you wanted to put "$\mathcal Z(f)=$" in every line, e.g.

$$\Leftrightarrow \mathcal Z(f)=(h_2\circ h_2^{-1})\circ g\circ (h_1 \circ h_1^{-1})$$

etc.